# How can make Entity Framework overwrite an existing database instead of creating a new one?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, appharbor, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to deploy Entity Framework on AppHarbor, and I want it to be able to migrate using automatic migrations.

What I'm having trouble doing, is in the AppHarbor database having the dbo._MigrationHistory table in System Tables. In AppHarbor I don't have permission to create a database from scratch (so I can't make EF create it) , and I can't restore it using a backup. The only thing I can do, I think, is use the Import/Export wizard of SQL Server, which does not copy the System Tables. So creating the database locally and exporting it to the AppHarbor server is ruled out.

A solution to this problem, and many other that I had in the past using EF, is to make EF do the same routines as creating the database, but only deleting everything on an existing database and starting from there. NHibernate does it like that. Can I make EF do it?

The DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged IDatabaseInitializer suggested by AppHarbor does not quite do that unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [custom SQL generator](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/02/27/code-first-migrations-making-__migrationhistory-not-a-system-table/) which will not use `MigrationHistory` as a system table.

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you. I tested it and it works like a charm.